# Add multiple Gmail accounts in Gmail app

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to do this?

I currently have Android 4.1.2 on an S3, and while I can do this on the e-mail app, I much prefer to use the Gmail app for its interface.

I know that this was possible in earlier versions.

Is this still possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do within Gmail. (In fact, there's nothing you *can* do in Gmail.)

Simply add the Google account(s) to your device under `Settings > Accounts > Add account`. (It will then appear there listed under "Google Account".)

After that make sure you're syncing Gmail plus whatever other Google services you want (or not).